# Infinite Input by user in an string scanned by character by character

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a program that will count the frequency of the character and printf it along with the character.

However for a given string my program is taking infinite input of the last character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct value
{
    long long as;
    long long k;
};

int main()
{
    long long count[128] = {0};
    char c;
    struct value max;
    max.k = 0; max.as = -1;

    // Upto Here was only initialization.

    while(1)
    {

        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("%c",c);
        if(c!='\n')
        {
            count[c]++;
            if(max.as<count[c])
            {
                max.as = count[c];
                max.k = c;
            }
            if(max.as==count[c]&&max.k<c)
            {
                max.k = c;
            }
        }
        else break; // Apparently this is never executed.
    }

     printf("\n%c %lld",(char)(max.k),max.as);
}
```

Like for the input "masaka" here gives output as "masakaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" where a is printed until output limit is reached.

Why is this happening here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. My compilation outputs `masaka masaka a 3`

Comment: @WeatherVane
GeeksforGeeks IDE is giving infinte output.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't posted the same code here.

Comment: [Geekforgeek code link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Vtzackv1Uf)
There you can see I guess. Though I tried few more compilers everyone is showing runtime exceeded.

Comment: You have no newline at the end of your input. Your code doesn't check for EOF.

Comment: your condition to stop is '\n', so add enter after 'masaka' in your example

Comment: @Barmar But the user will hit enter at the end of the input right?

Comment: I was running from a console. If I redirect input from a file that lacks a newline, the code fails: because there is no newline.

Comment: @KudoShinichi Not necessarily -- you didn't when you created your Geekforgeek page. Or if the input is a file.

Comment: So the lesson is ***always check the return value*** from the `scanf` function family. `if(scanf("%c",&c) != 1) { /* handle EOF or other */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will loop if the input does not have a newline in it, since it doesn't check for EOF.

`scanf()` will return `EOF` if it reaches end-of-file before parsing any inputs.

```
while(1)
{

    int result = scanf("%c",&c);
    if (result == EOF || result == 0) {
        break;
    }
    printf("%c",c);
    if(c!='\n')
    {
        count[c]++;
        if(max.as<count[c])
        {
            max.as = count[c];
            max.k = c;
        }
        if(max.as==count[c]&&max.k<c)
        {
            max.k = c;
        }
    }
    else break; // Apparently this is never executed.
}
```

Comment: @KudoShinichi `count` is the number of items successfully converted. That was probably not  intended to conflict with your `count[]` array.

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice you already had a variable named `count`, I've renamed it in my answer.